# Unable to accept single answer before bounty expired

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties

This looks a little like [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32358/unable-to-accept-answer-for-a-question-with-a-bounty) but is not - I posted a bounty and there was a [single answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174621/blend-window-is-not-supported-in-a-wpf-project/2504038#2504038) on the last day. I reviewed the answer and wanted to accept it but the "accept tick" was not visible.

I upvoted the answer and commented **before the bounty ran out** that I was unable to accept the answer.

I think this may have been a bug because there was only one upvoted answer to the question, which I know disables the auto-acceptance but appears to have disabled manual acceptance too.

Answer (score 1):

You posted the bounty on the 16th, and it expired on the 23rd.  I can't tell what time you placed the bounty, and what time you tried to accept the answer, but if it was over 168 hours after placing the bounty, then the bounty expired.

Since the new answer did not have at least two upvotes when the bounty expired, then it was not automatically selected.

Comment: Dunno, I don't have records to verify but am certain that the "last day" banner was still showing when I read the answer. I suspect if there is a bug that it may be in removing that banner - I'm sure it was indicating the bounty was still running. I'm on GMT+8 time if that makes any difference.